# Python Selenium WebDriverException Empty HTML

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

My code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chome.service import Service

broswer = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(R"C:\ProgramData\Google\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

At the last line, I get a WebDriverException with the following details:

```
Message: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlsn="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Although it worked perfectly yesterday, for some reason it doesn't work today and the error message isn't really helpful to me. I've tried many different ChromeOptions, as well as with Edge and the EdgeDriver, but it's the same result with that empty HTML result and error. I've done a lot of Googling but can't find any solution that works, as every other post has a more detailed error to troubleshoot.

Comment: What do you mean by **creating** a webdriver object with Selenium ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The line "browser = webdriver.Chrome()" results in a WebDriverException error, with the message in the top code box saying the HTML is empty.

Comment: What OS, versions, RAM are you running on?

Comment: OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
RAM: 16 GB

Versions:
- Python: 3.10.5
- Selenium: 4.8.0
- Chrome: 108.0.5359.125 (32-bit)
- ChromeDriver: 109.0.5414.74
- Edge: 108.0.1462.54 (64-bit)
- Selenium WebDriver for Edge: unknown

Important to note:
1) I've tried reinstalling the drivers and downgrading both my Python and Selenium versions to the previous (in every combination)
2) I'm on a work computer so can't install, uninstall, update or downgrade any software that isn't made available to me